# How to get my old coc account back using play games

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've been playing coc for a long time and i connected it to play games. One day i accedentaly uninstalled it,  so how do i get it back using play games.  Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Just login to Google account, go to settings then click change account and then select your account.

Answer (score 0):

Google play games exists for each Google account, and one game has only one entry of your game progress in in their database which corresponds to the one you use.
Or simply

1. COC has one database, where there is an entry for your account.
2. If you logged in with the same account but you don't find your progress, then that means that entry for your account has been overwritten with your new account.
3. But there's hope for you , most game developers have a backup progress database, where an older version of your account's progress is saved.
4. So the best thing would be to contact customer care and tell them to restore the last save of your account.

I know my answer sounds obvious, but I hope it helps, because that's the only thing you can do for online games such as COC which are made so , to minimize(take that with a pinch of salt) hacks.